# How to change numbering of figures (subfloats more specifically in a minipage)?

Tags: subfloats, minipage

I have 6 figures in a 2 by 3 minipage like below

```
\begin{minipage}
   \subfloat[]  
   \subfloat[] 
   \subfloat[]
   \quad
   \subfloat[]
   \subfloat[]
   \subfloat[]
\end{minipage}
```

This structure labels subfloat as

```
a b c
d e f
```

How I can get subfloats labeled as below ?

```
a c e
b d e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired layout, you could employ the following grouping of `\minipage` and `\subfloat` instructions:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
   \subfloat[]  
   \subfloat[] 
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
   \subfloat[]
   \subfloat[]
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
   \subfloat[]
   \subfloat[]
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use three minipages as columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \subfloat[]{A}\\
      \subfloat[]{B}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \subfloat[]{C}\\
      \subfloat[]{D}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{center}  
      \subfloat[]{E}\\
      \subfloat[]{F}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{All six.}
  \label{fig:allsix}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]