# I want to change the order of numbering for captions in subfigure

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

By default the rows are numbered
and then it moves to next column
like 
1,2

3,4

but I want to number it as

1,3

2,4

viz.,

|Figure 1 | Figure 3 |

|Figure 2 | Figure 4 |

How to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think there is already a question similar to this one: does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153122/how-to-change-numbering-of-figures-subfloats-more-specifically-in-a-minipage help?

Comment: Do you want a list of figures, and if so do you want to include the subfigure captions, and will you place the figure caption AFTER the subfigure captions?  If not, you don't really need subfigures at all.  \captionof{subfigure}{} will do.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a `multicol` with two columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
     \centering
      \subfloat[]{A}\par
      \subfloat[]{B}\par
      \subfloat[]{C}\par
      \subfloat[]{D}\par
      \subfloat[]{E}\par
      \subfloat[]{F}
    \end{multicols}
  \caption{All six.}
  \label{fig:allsix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{multicols}{2}
     \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \par
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \par
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \par
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \par
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \par
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{multicols}
  \caption{All six.}
  \label{fig:allsix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: minipages would work better than multicols.  multicols and floats are generally not compatible.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Really? I don't think so. It depends on where you use them. Use them inside float.

Answer (score 1):

This solution preserves the horizontal alignment of rows (if it ever comes up).  It works because the global counter is changed immediately, even though the savebox is not displayed until later.

Note that you could even display the boxes in random order.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\sbox0{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% a
\sbox1{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% b
\sbox2{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% c
\sbox3{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% d
\sbox4{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% e
\sbox5{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}}% f
\centering
  \usebox0\hfil \usebox3\par
  \usebox1\hfil \usebox4\par
  \usebox2\hfil \usebox5
  \caption{All six.}
  \label{fig:allsix}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```