# How to put the order of subfigures labeling by column instead of rowwise?

Tags: floats, labels

I have a code here:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, doublespacing, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={bf,small},skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font={small}, skip=1pt, singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\newcommand\msk{\medskip}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\text{\footnotesize{$c = 30\%$}}\par\medskip
\caption{}
\label{fig:PPa}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight, keepaspectratio]{PPSh.png}
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\text{\footnotesize{$c = 80\%$}}\par\medskip
\caption{}
\label{fig:PPb}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight, keepaspectratio]{PPSh80.png}
\end{subfigure}


\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{}
\label{fig:PPc}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight, keepaspectratio]{PPIa30.png}
\text{\footnotesize{Time (days)}}\par\medskip
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{}
\label{fig:PPd}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight, keepaspectratio]{PPIa80.png}
\text{\footnotesize{Time (days)}}\par\medskip
\end{subfigure}
\caption{State trajectories of human personal protection model.}
\label{fig:personalprotectiongraph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the output shows in the following:
[image]

Instead of having the first row be labelled as (a) and (b), I want the left column to be labeled as (a) and (b) and for the right column to be (c) and (d). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235690/i-want-to-change-the-order-of-numbering-for-captions-in-subfigure help?