# Multiple figure captions in column-row order

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I have 4 figures and I want each one of them to have a caption. For example, if I follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side), they will look like

```
Fig1.   Fig2.
(a)     (b)
Fig3.   Fig4.
(c)     (d)
```

But I want their caption to be organized as

```
Fig1.   Fig3.
(a)     (c)
Fig2.   Fig4.
(b)     (d)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235690/i-want-to-change-the-order-of-numbering-for-captions-in-subfigure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the counter `subcaption` to change the numbering order.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A subfigure 1}
        \label{fig:sub1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \setcounter{subfigure}{2} % set next caption to c
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A subfigure 2}
        \label{fig:sub2}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \setcounter{subfigure}{1} % set next caption to b
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A subfigure 3}
        \label{fig:sub3}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \setcounter{subfigure}{3} % set next caption to d
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{A subfigure 4}
        \label{fig:sub4}
    \end{subfigure}     
    \caption{ Main caption}\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
    
See the figure~\ref{fig:sub2} in the upper left of the Figure~\ref{fig:main}.
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question: use subfloats

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[figure]{font=sf}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Subfigure 1/4 \label{subfig:s1}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \setcounter{subfigure}{2}  % set next caption to c
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Subfigure 3/4 \label{subfig:s2}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
    \bigskip
    \setcounter{subfigure}{1} % set next caption to b
    \subfloat[Subfigure 2/4 \label{subfig:s3}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \setcounter{subfigure}{3} % set next caption to d
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Subfigure 4/4 \label{subfig:s4}]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
    \caption{ Main caption}\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

See the figure~\ref{subfig:s2} in the upper left of the Figure~\ref{fig:main}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I can't use subfigure. Could you provide an example with subfloat?

Comment: @fatpanda2049  I added an update using subfloats.

Answer (score 0):

With us of the `minipage` for grouping figures in column:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[figure]{font=sf}
    \captionsetup[sub]{skip=1ex, belowskip=2ex, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \subfloat[Subfigure 1/4 \label{subfig:s1}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

    \subfloat[Subfigure 2/4 \label{subfig:s2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}} 
\end{minipage}
    \hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \subfloat[Subfigure 3/4 \label{subfig:s3}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

    \subfloat[Subfigure 4/4 \label{subfig:s4}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Main caption}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

See the figure~\ref{subfig:s2} in the bottom left of the Figure~\ref{fig:main}.

\end{document}
```

[image]